# Faster Update in specific case: Join Large with equals or smaller with >- and <=

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have one large Master Table, TableA with 12 Million Records. The core of it was:

**TableA:**
|--FieldA--|--FieldP--|--FieldS--|--FieldH--|--ValueField--|--FieldX--|

I created two subtables from that:

TableB with about 5 million unique records based on FieldA,FieldP,FieldS where I also pushed Value as I didn't need FieldX. I

**TableB:** |--FieldA--|--FieldP--|--FieldS--|--FieldH--|--ValueField

TableC with about 200,000 records which pulled the upper and lower value fields for each unique FieldH,FieldP,FieldS:

**TableC:** |--FieldP--|--FieldS--|--FieldH--|--MaxValue--|--MinValue--|

I neglected to push FieldH into TableB initially and have done a lot of work to it in the interim so cannot redo that step.

There is no way for me to test performance so just asking the following question hoping this is enough information:

To update TableB with the FieldH data it started with in TableA I have two choices:

```
Update TableB as T1
Inner Join TableA as T2
On T1.FieldA=T2.FieldA
And T1.FieldP=T2.FieldP
And T2. FieldS=T2.FieldS
Set T1.FieldH=T2.FieldH
```

I have indexes on each of the select fields.

This seems like a massive join to me.

My other option is to use the ranges and do a smaller join with more calculations:

```
Update TableB as T1
Inner Join TableC as T2
On T1.ValueField>=T2.MinValue
And T1.ValueField<=T2.MaxValue
Set T1.FieldH=T2.FieldH
```

I have an index on the value field as well.

Clearly in the latter case the advantage is it is a far smaller join, but on the other hand I am adding numeric calculations to each record. I don't know enough about the inner workings on indexes or joins or calculations to even make an educated guess on which is better.

I hope I provided a clear picture here. Trying not to add more and over-complicate the question, if any add'l data would help I am happy to provide/elaborate.

Comment: Did you try the "complex" join? doesnt look really difficult for the db

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza By complex you mean calculations? I didn't try either yet as so far various joins here are taking quite awhile so just letting either rip becomes a guessing game. It appears from your comment however I might be overestimatng the overhead >= <= are going to add.

Comment: Ohh I see it now. You want update `Table B` using `Table A` or `Table C`. I tought you was scare of using a 12 millions rows `Table A`. First what you mean `cant test performace` ? You should be able to run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) That is the only way you can compare performance between both querys

Comment: I really dont think option 2) can give you the result your want. That `>=  and <=` condition ... probably can return multiple rows, and wont be able to update.\

Answer (score 0):

I'll refer you to this question (which I finally answered):

[Faster Update in specific case: Join Large with equals or smaller with >- and <=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148197/faster-update-in-specific-case-join-large-with-equals-or-smaller-with-and)

which was an outgrowth of this one. I got to the point where I realized it was not the >=<= but my indexing itself and specifically my need to create a compound index AND to have MySql choose it. So tackled that question instead.

Long story short is since I needed to join two large tables with concatenated varchar fields, I made an intermediate table and used those IDs to join instead. Please see the link above if you need details.

In the end it worked great even using the >=<=, in fact it ended up doing 52k updates on a 5 million record to 5 million record table in just over a minute (where it was taking 10 seconds per record prior).